# AppleScript: trying to press "w" but getting "wa"

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to press just 'w' but 'a' is pressed along with it.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key down (key code 13)'
```

How can I get AppleScript to just send the 'w'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling Applescript to send `key down` *and* `key code 13`.

Just use the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 13'
```